# Delete using Ajax and jquery is not working

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

i am trying to delete using ajax. where is the mistake?

```
    $(function () {
        $("#del").on('click','button',function ($a){
            $.ajax({
                url: "logical.php?action=del",
                type: 'POST',
                data: new FormData(this),
                contentType: false,
                cache: false,
                processData: false,
                success: function(data) {
                    $("#showdata").html(data);
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
```

the button code is

```
<td align="center"> <button type="button" id="del" '<?php $a="$fetch ['news_id'];" ?>'> Delete </button> </td>
```

Comment: you have written `botton` instead of `button` in selector

Comment: corrected--still not working

Comment: what's the error coming in console

Comment: Is `button` a child of `id=del`?  Looks like they're the same...

Comment: Test your selector in the browser console:  `$("#del").find("button").length`

Comment: Did you mean: `$("#del").on('click',function () {` ?

Comment: Shouldn't you pass the `newsid` via Ajax??

Comment: No error in console

Comment: You've got everyone playing guessing game!  Where is the problem??!!!  Client side or server side?!!

Comment: @Akintunde well, we've found 2 obvious issues in the client side - button/botton and `<button id=del>` won't match `$("#id button")`.  *Neither of these would give an error in the console* and both would stop it getting to the server side

Comment: when i click on delete button, in network, it should show

Comment: `function ($a)` what's `$a` in there

Comment: Sanchit, look at button tag, $a is id of that row

Comment: `$a` is a php variable, not a javascript one.   It's not used in the call anyway, so just ignored.

Comment: so what should be done so that the url is passed in network???

Comment: @AnilSangwa Can you inspect the button and attach a screenshot of DOM for the button

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the `'button'` param on your event. It says : "Look for the button child of the `#del` element, while you want to attach the `click` event directly on the `#del` element.

Try this :

```
    $("#del").on('click', function ($a){
        $.ajax({
            url: "logical.php?action=del",
            type: 'POST',
            data: new FormData(this),
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function(data) {
                $("#showdata").html(data);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
```

It should work correctly this way.

Comment: when i click on delete button, in network, it should show  'logical.php?action=del'      but its not showing

Comment: You should see it only if the event has been triggered, which is not the case if the selector is wrong !